# The navigation bar disappears when signing out user

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, logout

When I log out a user from the app, the **navigation bar disappears.**

The navigation bar disappears if the user log out and sign in again.
How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logOut" sender:self];


}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"logOut"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code in your sign in view controller below or above viewDidLoad method

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false animated:false];
}
```

may be it helps you....

Comment: Thanks. Finally I got it to work with: [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

Comment: **But** i just realiser when you click on the *third tab* the user goes back to settings instead of showing up in the *third tab*. Settings is a hidden view that you have to go to from the *third tab.* Any ideas? Maybe I need to dismiss settings and then dismiss the *third tabbar* when signing out?

Comment: can you explain in Detail... If possible can you put your snapshot related to problems

Comment: In my project I have a tab bar controller with a navigation bar. Tab 0, Tab 1, Tab 2. In the first view in Tab 2 I have the User Profile for the app, and from User Profile I have a seque that pushes to a second view that is called Settings. In the Settings view I have my logout button. When I logout a user and log in again and press **Tab 2** I show up in Settings instead of User Profile. I want to show up in User Profile instead. **Basically I always want to show up in the start view of my tab when I go to my tab. Does it make sense? PS: Don't have rep enough to post photos

Comment: Ok. it means you r clicking on settings from user profile view controller which is your third tab bar.. so when you logout from settings then you should have to pop to view controller on UserProfile and then code for popping back on sign inn screen.. Means on logout button click you have to popToViewController:ViewProfile and in next line popToViewController:signInViewController...

Comment: Thanks! Yes something like this. But the tab bar disappears now instead when I use for example: - (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

Comment: why you use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` Both....?

Comment: Just trying out diffrent solutions.. Any ideas?

Comment: No because if you can show whole the flow and what you wants to do on which control then i understood those things and can give you ideas or solutions... sorry...